# Typescript + Vite + Vue 3 syntax error not showing when component is called

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

i have a problem with typescript in vue 3 with "script setup (SFC)".
When i call the component into (for example) App.vue and insert the props, if one of these is inserted wrong, the editor does not report the error.

An example:

[image]

[image]

The type value:

```
type Type = 'primary' | 'danger' | 'warning'
```

Why "non" type not showing error? I use PHPStorm, but this not showing also in VScode.

Comment: are you using volar extension?

Comment: You should be using Volar extension for Vue.js in VSCode and disable Vetur. If you prefer JetBrains more, then you should be using Webstorm.

Comment: I use phpstorm (webstorm is integrate). But in webstorm does not work the same. Is there any particular extension you need to enable? And in VSCode with volar not working. Is the "script setup" the problem?

Comment: "in VSCode with volar not working" can you elaborate? This extension is actively maintained, and works smoothly on my machine

Comment: I have done endless checks but it doesn’t work I don’t know why. But my main problem is not vscode as I use phpstorm/webstorm.